# Non blocking Dhcpcd via Systemctl

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, startup

I have seen the `--no-block` argument with *systemctl start* but I have no idea how to have this in a config (ex.: */usr/lib/systemd/system/dchcpcd.service*) or do this with the `systemctl enable` command.

If this is explicitly not possible, and I would have to run this in .Xinitrc or the wm (i3 for me) config file with `systemctl start ... --no-block`, then my question changes to, how do all the other distributions of Linux deal with this (the 1.5 minute blocking on startup -- I know you can lower it, but that's not the point)?

P.S.: And yeah, obviously this doesn't work:

```
sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd@enp8s0.service --no-block
```

Comment: I suspect many distributions use NetworkManager or something else that's able to start even without being able to establish a network connection instead of using the dhcpcd service.

Comment: @Wieland Hmm.. I didn't even know about NetworkManager up until now, but I think I'm gonna pass. I will either try to fix this, or write my own script (and daemonize it in *.xinitrc*) to simplify things.